# Can you apply a terraform file called something other than Main?

Tags: azure, terraform

In terraform is it possible to have multiple .tf files for different things

eg I want to use a vm.tf for vms and a keyvault.tf for keyvaults

Is this possible? If do what is the format to use these file names when building infrastructure?#

for example Ive tried terraform plan keyvualt.tf , but it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple .tf files in same directory.

Terraform reads all of the .tf files in the directory(scans the current directory for the configuration) and applies the changes appropriately.

You can split terraform code from your main.tf file into separate .tf files in the same directory.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html